# Maximizing the probability of Bernoulli Sums

Tags: probability

Suppose I have $X_1,\cdots X_n$ with $X_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p_i)$, here  we only assume $X_1,\cdots X_n$ are independent but not neccessarily identical so there are n degree of freedom.

Now,  I want to show that the probability that
$$\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = m)$$ is maximized at $p_i = \frac{m}{n}$. How do I do that? It seems intuitive proving it is hard.

Comment: What do you mean by "Now, I know that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = m$" ?

Comment: Ignore that line. However, I just want to maximize the probability with $p_i$.

Comment: It is not maximized at the point you say. Assume $m$ is an integer in $\{0,1,...,n\}$. The maximizing probability is 1, achieved by $p_i=1$ for $i\in  \{1,...,m\}$ and $p_i=0$ else.

Comment: not really right? What we have is that this is regardless of the actual sequence, as long as the sum is $m$. So the probability of all the sum has to add together.

Comment: I do not know what you are talking about.  It is obvious that $P[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=m]=1$ if we choose probabilities as I suggested.

Comment: You are right. This means I should put a prior on sequences. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not make sense. Consider these changes to you exercise and tell me if it can be what you are looking for:

- the $n$ Bernulli's iid rv $X_i$
- $$Y= \sum_i X_i \sim Bin(n;p)$$

So Y is again a rv taking values in $y=\{0;1;2;...;n\}$. Let's suppose that the result of the sum is a fixed $0 \leq m \leq n$

The goal is to maximize the probability

$$\mathbb{P}[Y=m]=\binom{n}{m}p^m(1-p)^{n-m}$$

as we have to maximize the function with respect to $p$ we can take into consideration only

$$\mathbb{P}[Y=m]=p^m(1-p)^{n-m}$$

Let's take the log (log is a monotone transformation so it doesn't change the argmax)

$$log P=mlog p+(n-m)log(1-p)$$

Let's derive with respect to $p$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial p}log P=\frac{m}{p}-\frac{n-m}{1-p}$$

setting it =0 and solving with respect to $p$ you find

$p=\frac{m}{n}$

It is obviuosly a maximum, but you can check it with calculating the second derivative

Comment: Not what I am asking, I am just asking if $X_1 \cdots X_n$ independent but necessarily identically distributed. The Binomial MLE is well known but the independent Bernoulli ones are not.

Comment: This answer interprets the question in a way that makes the answer interesting. MLE is not useful when there are too many degrees of freedom as the answer can degenerate to a max probability of 1 as it does in your case ( see my comment above).